# Trying to take a sentence with numbers and change the numbers into words. then print the sentence wit the changes

Tags: python, arrays

## change the numaruls into the word

```
list_of_nums =["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"]

text = "2 apples and 6 pears"
a = text.split()
text_splt = []


for x in a:
    if x in list_of_nums:
        text = text.replace(x,text_splt[list_of_nums(x)])
print(text)
```

I also tried

```
arr.append(a)
print(arr)
print(list_of_nums)
arr.insert(0,list_of_nums[2])

print(arr)
```

## need the index of the first array to compare to the value of whats index in the second array

but this ended in a error

Comment: What is the purpose of `text_splt`?  It starts as an empty list and you never add anything to it...

Comment: it was originally labeled arr as seen in the second half of my post it was updated for easier reading.

Comment: was trying to create a second array split by words instead of letters

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list of numbers and replace each index with the word at that index.

```py
for i, x in enumerate(list_of_nums):
    text = text.replace(str(i), x)
```

You could also use a regular expression to match single digits.

```py
import re
text = re.sub(r'\b\d\b', lambda m: list_of_nums[int(m.group())], text)
```

Comment: ok i havent gotten to enumerate or lambda yet i just finished learning about dictionaries and tuples. is this the only solution to the problem?

Comment: @marsmontgomery You don't need enumerate; you can keep a separate counter outside the loop.